# Android: Where does "D/AppTracker: App Event: stop" came from

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, accountmanager

I am programming an android app with the Google AccountManager.
In the log monitor I get these line "D/AppTracker: App Event: stop" or "D/AppTracker: App Event: start"

Can I track these methods so I can use it for check AccountManager if user is still logged in?